# wrapping map access, smart or stupid?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm accessing a lot of maps in a non-performance critical piece of code. I don't want to write the usual find/!=end all the time to check for missing keys. I also don't want to use [] blindly and get default values. Is the following wrapper function smart or stupid? Is there a simpler way? Are there side effects I didn't consider?

```
template<typename M>
static typename M::mapped_type getMapValue(const M& m, typename M::key_type key) {

    typename M::const_iterator it = m.find(key);

    if (it != m.end()) {
        return it->second;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Key: " << key << " not found!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Returning default value." << std::endl;
        return typename M::mapped_type();
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I can see the only addition in funcitonality is to print an error. You could use `std::map::at()` instead, and get a nice exception that can't just be ignored.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `std::map::at()` is C++11 only.  I first thought you had confused it with vector!

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, I am thinking of `std::map`. It is a C++11 addition. Pretty useful too.

Comment: @juanchopanza: got it, sorry for the stealth edit there!  I upvoted your answer because I didn't know about that one before.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), then the client code has to decide how to deal with any `std::out_of_range` exception thrown from a call with a key that isn't already in the map.

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;

....
int n = m.at("hello!");
```

Comment: I'm not going to disagree with this solution in general, however, depending on the semantics you want the container to have, the OP's solution may be appropriate in his particular case.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I tend to agree. However, I think it is probably better to have to express in code "I know this is an error, and I chose to deal with it somehow", rather than blindly call a wrapper that just writes to `stderr`. The caller side has no way of knowing the returned value is somehow suspect.

Comment: Full ACK, juanchopanza. If you have access to C++ 11 and a missing key is an error, by all means stick to the `at()` function that is written exactly for this case. In other cases, wrapping the whole container is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

## Smart

Wrapping the `std` containers is normally a good idea, as it allows you to swap them out in the future should you so wish.

However, is returning the default value the correct behaviour? It may be in your case, but in most cases, it won't be.

Comment: Oh, the old "Write wrappers for everything so you can swap it out later."  I'm not a buyer: the STL is basically duck-typed, so you usually don't need to change much code if you swap out say a map for an unordered_map.

Comment: @JohnZwinck You need a copy of Meyer's Effective STL, good sir. The `std` containers aren't as swappable as they first appear.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the STL interface become cumbersome for some piece of program logic, I tend to wrap the whole container, not just access to a single function. Typically, I then derive privately from the existing container type and make the parts I need public again. In addition, I add the actual interface I need, like e.g. operator[] for a const map-like object:

```
struct mycontainer:
    private map<string, string>
{
    typedef map<string, string> base;
    using base::iterator;
    using base::const_iterator;
    using base::begin;
    using base::end;

    string const& operator[](string const& k) const
    {
        const_iterator it = find(k);
        if(it == end())
            throw runtime_error("lookup failure");
        return it->second;
    }
};
```

Notes:

- If you need special iterators, there is a helper library in Boost to ease creating custom iterator types.
- You can also change the interface significantly, e.g. returning a default value without adding it to the map or returning a boost::optional. The latter is IMHO *the* way to easily check for presence and retrieve the value in one step.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is checking, then you probably want something like:

```
if (theMap.count(theKey)) {
  doSomethingWith(theMap[theKey]);
} else {
  doSomethingDefault();
}
```

The name count is very awkward, since it just returns true if the element is there and false if it isn't.  I think it was supposed to be consistent with some container that supported multiple values per key, but then they never wrote that container.  It's probably not worth wrapping map just to rename "count" "contains".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off throwing an exception when the element is not found.  Who is going to monitor your program for all these warnings it will print, anyway?

Also, consider taking the key by const-reference, since `std::map` does.

Comment: Throwing an exception is okay, if it really is an exception that the key is not in the map. If it's 50/50 then maybe not.

Comment: If it's 50/50 then maybe it shouldn't write to stderr either.  :)